# What are the frequencies of each element of fft output in ArrayFire?

Tags: c++, fft, arrayfire

I am trying to compute derivatives via fft on the GPU using ArrayFire but i am not getting expected results.

What is the frequency of each element in the output of ArrayFire's fft, fft2, and fft3 functions (for both even and odd sized inputs) ?

For example, the frqeuency values of each element in the output of numpy's fft function is mentioned [here](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.fft.fftfreq.html#numpy.fft.fftfreq)

It would be great if someone could post a simplified working example of derivative using ArrayFire's fft (lets say something as simple as first and second derivative of f(x) = cos(x) or f(x) = x^2)

Comment: Looking at the [source of ArrayFire for cpu](https://github.com/arrayfire/arrayfire/blob/devel/src/backend/cpu/fft.cpp), it seems that ArrayFire wraps the [fftw](http://www.fftw.org/) library. So the frequencies should be similar to the one of fftw ([clfft](http://clmathlibraries.github.io/clFFT/) and cufft).

Comment: From the [documentation of fftw](http://www.fftw.org/fftw3_doc/The-1d-Discrete-Fourier-Transform-_0028DFT_0029.html#The-1d-Discrete-Fourier-Transform-_0028DFT_0029) : `the k-th output corresponds to the frequency k/n (or k/T, where T is your total sampling period). For those who like to think in terms of positive and negative frequencies, this means that the positive frequencies are stored in the first half of the output and the negative frequencies are stored in backwards order in the second half of the output. (The frequency -k/n is the same as the frequency (n-k)/n.) `

Comment: Note that these are the center frequencies of each element.  But each output element covers a bandwidth of greater than zero.

Comment: thanks for the answers. @francis I did get to this paragraph by digging into the code. But i find that documentation very superficial. I think my code has problems with corner cases. It doesnt say, how things change for even n versus odd n. fftw also has r2c to compute only the first half which makes things less confusing (see [here](http://www.dsprelated.com/showthread/comp.dsp/68934-1.php)) but ArrayFire doesnt seem to have this facility. I feel every library should have a function like numpy's fftfreq to avoid confusion.

Comment: I will try to write a simplified test code to highlight the problem i am facing sometime tonight.

Comment: @cdeepakroy : i agree with you that `fftfreq` is a really nice user-oriented feature and that fft libraries should have such a feature for debugging or learning. Or at least a function `freq(i,n)`. Most fft libraries are missing documentation and dedicated practical examples. And wrapping libraries should add links to the corresponding wrapped functions...